# Making SCNText objects always facing forward

Tags: ios, text, graph, drawing, scenekit

Is there a way for making SCNText objects always face the camera while animating scenes?

I'm working on a graph visualization app that displays nodes, edges, graphs, tress, ... etc.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you can use a `SCNLookAtConstraint` so that the text node always points toward the camera node.

Comment: Thanks @mnuages for the answer. My attempts so far are leading the text to look at either the scene's root node or the camera node. Both of which aren't helping.

I have made a link to a sample rendering: [https://www.dropbox.com/s/7scbadrzfdgxf6n/IMG_0075.jpg?dl=0](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7scbadrzfdgxf6n/IMG_0075.jpg?dl=0)

Comment: This make facing toward, not forward